# Create a third table from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables I have to utilize to create a third table. TableA does not contain all the information required since it only lists sources people used to learn about our company while TableB has all the possible sources listed that people can utilize. I want TableC to show 0% for the sources which were not used. How is this possible in postgreSQL?

```
select "Source", to_char(100 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (), '990%') as "The Ratio"
from TableA 
group by "Source";

Source:       The Ratio:

Website         55%
TV              25%
Radio           20%


Select * from Table2:


Source:

Website
TV
Radio
BillBoard
Referral
```

Result I humbly request assistance with:

```
Source:                The Ratio:

Website                 55%
TV                      25% 
Radio                   20%
BillBoard                0%
Referral                 0%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join the result with table2 like this:

```
select t2."Source", to_char(coalesce(t1."The Ratio",0),'990%') "The Ratio"
from table2 t2 left outer join
  (select "Source", 100 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over ()  "The Ratio"
   from TableA 
   group by "Source") t1
on t1."Source" = t2."Source";
```

Comment: It shows an error nvl (numeric,integer) does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You just want a `left join`:

```
select a."Source",
       to_char(100 * count(b.source) / sum(count(*)) over (), '990%') as "The Ratio"
from TableB b left join
     TableA a
     on a.source = b.source
group by a."Source";
```