# Have a zero if no Sales

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question is very identical to one in the attached post except that I need to have a where clause in my query pertinent to week from table1. My table2 (t2) has only one column (names) and no date/time columns while table1 (t1) has name, sales and week. I want to return a zero for Sean since he did not have any sales for the week ending 01/01/2017.

[Create a third table from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468601/create-a-third-table-from-two-tables/41468666#41468666)

```
select * from table2:

Names

Maggie
Colleen
Laura
Sean

select * from table1:

Names               Sales                Week
Maggie              1800                 01/01/2017
Colleen             2000                 01/01/2017  
Laura               4000                 01/01/2017
Sean                1500                 12/18/2016   

select t2.Name, coalesce(t1."Employee Sales",0) "Employee Sales"
from emphis t2 left outer join
(select Name, sum(Sales) "Employee Sales"
from empdata
group by Name) t1
on t1.Name = t2.Name

Names              Employee Sales              
Maggie              1800                 
Colleen             2000                 
Laura               4000                 
Sean                1500
```

The result I am looking for:

```
Names              Employee Sales            
Maggie              1800                 
Colleen             2000                 
Laura               4000                 
Sean                 0 

select t2.Name, coalesce(t1."Employee Sales",0) "Employee Sales"
from emphis t2 left outer join
(select Name, sum(Sales) "Employee Sales"
from empdata
group by Name) t1
on t1.Name = t2.Name
where t1.Week = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1
```

Error in postgreSQL:

```
ERROR:  column t1.Week does not exist
LINE 7: where t1.Week = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1
```

I use

```
where t1.Week = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1
```

to automate so I do not need to change the dates for every Sunday.

Comment: move the week condition to the `join` clause `.. on t1.Name = t2.Name
and t1.Week = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the "Week" condition inside the sub-select. This has two advantages:

1. You will get the partial sales amount for that week if someone has sales across multiple weeks.
2. They will show up in your list if they have no sales with $0

Like so:

```
select t2.Name,
    coalesce(t1."Employee Sales",0) "Employee Sales"
from emphis t2 
left outer join (
    select Name, 
        sum(Sales) "Employee Sales"
    from empdata
    where Week = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1
    group by Name
    ) t1
on t1.Name = t2.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's cause your subquery doesn't have that `Week` column included or selected. You should include that column as well like

```
(select Name, sum(Sales) "Employee Sales", "Week"
from empdata
group by Name) t1
on t1.Name = t2.Name
where t1.Week = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, Sean does not show up. Only the other three employees with Sales show up.

Comment: @Jacob_Cortese, it's mostly cause of the `where` condition. check and verify the same. Moreover, don't see why you need a `sum()` or `group by` here